# What does the Spider Mod add?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I am thinking about downloading [the spider mod](http://spidermod.spiderland.net/) for TBOI for the cool tweaks I heard it has, but I can't find information about them. What exactly does the spider mod add?

Comment: what spider mod?

Comment: @Ender [The Spider Mod](http://spidermod.spiderland.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Welp. It says this on the main page.

Main features are:

Almost everything is seeded.
In Game item description (provided by Elucidate)
Boss presets for floor editor
Fractional HP on hit (hp/maxhp) information.
2 saves!
Spawn game objects

Comment: what does it mean when it says 'everything is seeded'? Whats 'seeded'?

Comment: @Ender seeds are numbers used to calculate "randomness", this way you can get the same "random" items/floors/bosses etc in each playthrough, as long you use that seed. Good for competition or optimization